# Sub-Menu Hover Only Partionaly Working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, onhover

Here it is:

http://gyazo.com/e94edf3c9b10bc33c2d9be8ed049583e

As you can see, the submenu works, and when I hover over something on the submenu, it creates a grey background. The problem is, once I get under "Sports Edition", the hover basically cancels and closes the submenu. It stops right where that blue line begins.

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="toprightunder">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Content options</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Default Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News Edition </a>li>
                <li><a href="#">Entertainment Edition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports Edition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Latino Edition</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: (there is a lot because I was testing a lot)

```
#toprightunder {
    margin-top:18px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    right:0;
}
#toprightunder a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
    margin-left:0;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#toprightunder ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*text-align:right;*/
    position:relative;
    display:inline-table;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
#toprightunder ul li {
    display:inline;
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
    font-family:"arial", times, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-top:13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
#toprightunder ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#toprightunder ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
#toprightunder ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    margin-right:0;
    right:0px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
#toprightunder ul ul li {
    position:relative;
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    /*margin-bottom:10px;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:4px;*/
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
#toprightunder ul ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0;
    position:relative;
}
#toprightunder a:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
#toprightunder ul li:hover > li {
    background-color:transparent;
}
#toprightunder ul ul li:hover > a {
    color:rgb(50, 50, 50);
    background:rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#toprightunder ul ul li > a {
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:25px;
    width:100%;
}

#headbar a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
    }

#headbar ul ul {
    display:none;
    }

#headbar ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    color:green;
    }

#headbar ul {
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:1px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    }

#headbar ul li {
    display:inline;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-top:3px;
    font-family:"arial", times, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    }

#headbar ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    padding-top:6px;
    }

#headbar ul ul li {
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    color:rgb(100,100,100);
    font-size:16px;
    }

#headbar ul ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    }

#headbar ul ul li a:hover {
    }


/*#headbar ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display:block;*/


#headbar a:hover {
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    color:rgb(100,100,100);
    }

#headbar ul li:hover > a{
    color:rgb(50,50,50);
    background-color:transparent;
    padding-top:8px;
    }

#headbar ul ul li > a {
    color:rgb(100,100,100);
    padding-top:8px;
    }

#headbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(30,144,255);
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:129px;
    text-align: left;
    /*position:relative;*/
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? What CSS properties are assigned to the blue bar?

Comment: I just added it to the bottom. It is called #headbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index: 2;` to the `#toprightunder` selector and that should resolve your problem.

```
#toprightunder {
    margin-top:18px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    right:0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```